# iOS Eureka: How to select first value as default after lazy get

Tags: ios, eureka-forms

I have a list retrieved from REST API to Eureka's PushRow, but in case none is selected (creating a new object) I want first option to be selected by default after option list is retrieved.

However, PushRow only loads list after it's clicked on.

So is there a way to load PushRow lazy options together with it's section, or should I switch to other type of row (if it support's lazy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$0.value    // To set default value for PushRow()
```

Check that value is there before set to `$0.value`

Here what i used

```
<<< PushRow<String>(){
    $0.tag = String(index)
    $0.selectorTitle = checklistFieldNames[index] //
    $0.options = ["YES", "NO"]
    if question.count == 0{
       $0.value = ""
    }else {
       $0.value = checklistFieldAnswers[0]
    }
    }.onPresent({ (from, to) in
        to.dismissOnChange = false
        to.dismissOnSelection = true
        to.tableView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 244/255, green: 244/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)
        to.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 244/255, green: 244/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0)
        to.selectableRowCellUpdate = { cell, row in
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "DTLProkyonT", size: 15)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
   }
})
```

Comment: I know about $0.value but I use lazy to pull that data from API, but that data isn't loaded until PushRow is opened first time, meaning unless you click on it atleast once, it has a null value